# Трибоначчи рекурсивно

Tags: python

Можно ли сделать рекурсивно числа трибоначчи на питоне?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Числа_трибоначчи почитайте перед тем как дать новый ответ с числами фибоначи

Answer (score 3):

```
def tribonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 0
    if n in (3,):
        return 1
    return tribonacci(n - 1) + tribonacci(n - 2) + tribonacci(n - 3)
```

Comment: вот смотри, если в tribonacci(n-1) подсунуть расчитанные tribonacci(n - 2), а в (n-2) уже  будет расчитанно (n-3) - вот его и протащить вторым параметром до (n-1)

Comment: Нужно учитывать, что сложность вычисления быстро растёт и уже где-то 30-й элемент считается порядка 4 секунды. Так что для больших членов последовательности надо либо переписывать на не-рекурсивную версию, либо можно воспользоваться декоратором `lru_cache` из functools и тогда работает за микросекунды даже для очень больших номеров ряда.

Comment: если я ввожу print(tribonacci(0)) вылетает с ошибкой

Comment: @eri Ясен пень не считать уже однажды считанное - и разумнее, и быстрее. Но задача учебная, и если у автора вопрос вообще возник - ему и такого решения за глаза хватит.

Comment: @Some_Body *если я ввожу print(tribonacci(0)) вылетает с ошибкой* Текущий текст нумерует элементы, начиная с первого. Хотите с нулевого - уменьшите на единицу все границы у обоих IF-ов.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

В разы быстрее варианта @Akina, 70ый меньше чем за секунду

```
def tribonacci(n, n2=None, n3=None):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 0
    if n in (3,):
        return 1

    n3 = n3 or tribonacci(n - 3)    
    n2 = n2 or tribonacci(n - 2, n3)

    return tribonacci(n - 1, n2, n3) + n2 + n3

tribonacci(70)
```

Но на кеше всеравно быстрее

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=4)
def tribonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 0
    if n in (3,):
        return 1
    return tribonacci(n - 1) + tribonacci(n - 2) + tribonacci(n - 3)

tribonacci(100)
```

Comment: Вообще это какое-то промежуточное решение. Либо полностью рекурсивно делать (и с кэшем, например, да), либо полностью не-рекурсивное решение делать. Так то, конечно, быстрее чем полностью рекурсивно, но ни туда ни сюда получается :)

Comment: это решение ещё остается рекурсивным)

Answer (score 0):

```
  n=int(input())
  a=0
  b=0
  c=1
  while n>0:
    n-=1
    h=a+b+c
    a=b
    b=c
    c=h
  print(c-a-b)  
  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
```

Comment: И что выдаст при n = 1? )

Answer (score -2):

**Рекурсивное вычисление n-го числа ряда Фибоначчи**

1. Если n = 1 или n = 2, вернуть в вызывающую ветку единицу, так как первый и второй элементы ряда Фибоначчи равны единице.
2. Во всех остальных случаях вызвать эту же функцию с аргументами n - 1 и n - 2. Результат двух вызовов сложить и вернуть в вызывающую ветку программы.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)

print(fibonacci(10))
```

Допустим, n = 4. Тогда произойдет рекурсивный вызов fibonacci(3) и fibonacci(2). Второй вернет единицу, а первый приведет к еще двум вызовам функции: fibonacci(2) и fibonacci(1). Оба вызова вернут единицу, в сумме будет два. Таким образом, вызов fibonacci(3) возвращает число 2, которое суммируется с числом 1 от вызова fibonacci(2). Результат 3 возвращается в основную ветку программы. Четвертый элемент ряда Фибоначчи равен трем: 1 1 2 3.